# GenericPublisher using ShapeShifter and SerializedMessage

Tags: ros, topic-tools, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to write a generic publisher that is able to publish ros-topics where each instance of this class publishes topics of different message types (e.g. pub_1 publishes std_msg::Int32, pub_2 publishes sensor_msgs::PointCloud2,...).

I work with serialized messages, i.e.:

```
ros::serialization::IStream i_stream((u_int8_t*) testArray.data(), m_genericRosTopic.SerializedMessageSize);
```

contains my serialized message which I want to publish. I also know the message type and the topic_name, that I want to publish on.

How can I do this in a generic way?
I saw that the ros::Publisher class has a publish() function that is able to publish a ros::SerializedMessage.

Thus, I made a SerializedMessage from the IStream:

```
boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buf(i_stream.getData());
ros::SerializedMessage msg(buf, i_stream.getLength());
```

My generic publisher class has a ros::Publisher as a member. For advertising, I found:

```
m_genericRosTopic_publisher = m_shapeShifter.advertise(n, m_genericRosTopic.TopicName, 10);
```

After that I would like to publish the topic somehow:

```
m_genericRosTopic_publisher.publish(msg);
```

Publishing like this doesn't work. I guess there is still something missing.
But it seems that everything I need is already there (somewhere in roscpp), but I am not able to put the puzzle together.

Can someone help me out here, by clarifying the correct usage of topic_tools::ShapeShifter, ros::SerializedMessage and ros::Publisher?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12312/genericpublisher-using-shapeshifter-and-serializedmessage/) by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem:

The ByteArrayMessage::serialize function is called as soon as a subscriber subscribes to the topic published by the GenericPublisher. The publisher than has to write the data from buffer_ to the write_ptr given by the subscriber.

Thus the function looks like this:

```
const uint8_t* ByteArrayMessage::serialize(uint8_t *write_ptr, uint32_t seq) const
{
    ros::serialization::OStream stream(write_ptr, 1000000000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length_; i++) 
    {
      stream.next(buffer_[i]);
    }

    return stream.getData();
}
```

I don't need the Serializer struct.

Thanks for your help!

---

Originally posted by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) with karma: 198 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on 2011-12-19**:
Hmm. It works under electric! So what is the deprecated part? The functions of the Serializer are not used. What am I missing?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-12-19**:
Don't forget that the interface you are implementing is already deprecated. Your code will not work under electric and newer ROS releases.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2017-09-11**:
Hey Lorenz, do you have that code anywhere? I couldn't find it on your Github

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the reply, Lorenz.

Maybe, I didn't say it clear enough:
Each generic publisher is only publishing on one single topic. The type, the topic_name, message_definition and md5sum does not change once advertised. But each instance of this generic publisher class publishes a topic of a different type.
(instance pub_1 of GenericPublisher publishes only messages of type std::Int32, instance pub_2 of GenericPublisher publishes messages of type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2,...)

In the meantime, I also know the md5sum and the message definition within GenericPublisher.

Thus I can advertise as followed:

```
ros::AdvertiseOptions opts( "/generic_topic_opc_client"+m_genericRosTopic.TopicName, 10, m_genericRosTopic.MD5Sum, m_genericRosTopic.MessageDataType, m_genericRosTopic.MessageDefinition);
m_genericRosTopic_publisher = n.advertise(opts);
```

Still, I don't know what

```
m_genericRosTopic_publisher.publish()
```

expects as a parameter and how I can get this parameter from

```
ros::serialization::IStream i_stream((u_int8_t*) testArray.data(), m_genericRosTopic.SerializedMessageSize);
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) with karma: 198 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-12-12**:
Sorry. I guess it was my fault, I didn't read your post careful enough. I updated my answer. Hopefully this time it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing the same work. I am publishing topic_tools::ShapeShifter msg.
And I have got some help from rosbag package. Try to compare your class ByteArrayMessage with the class MessageInstance class in rosbag package. Its look very similar. But you will get much info from messgae_instance.h in rosbag package. In my code I have used that MessageInstance class by changing it a little.

Now to publish that message. get help from the following code. If we want to publish multiple topics we can use the following code. I have got help from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2590/first-image-message-does-not-get-published)

```
std::map<std::string, ros::Publisher> mPublishers;

ros::Publisher getPublisher(const std::string& topic, MessageInstance &m)
  {
 if (mPublishers.find(topic) == mPublishers.end())
 {
ros::AdvertiseOptions opts = createAdvertiseOptions(m, 10);

ros::NodeHandle mNh;
mPublishers[topic] = mNh.advertise(opts);
  }

return mPublishers[topic];
}
```

use that function

```
ros::Publisher pub = getPublisher(connection_info->topic, m);
pub.publish(m);
```

I hope that it will work.

---

Originally posted by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) with karma: 81 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1